# Beginning of class definition

Tags: c++, class

Formally (quote from std would be ideal), from which point a definition of this class starts:

```
template<typename T>
class X
{
};
```

Comment: Formally, this is not class. This is templated class.

Comment: @Alex correct wording if you want to be nit picking is class template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> from which point a definition of this class starts

From the point compiler starts parsing things related to the class. In your example, the letter **"t"** of the word `template` is the start, hence the point of definition!

By the way, there're two related things. Read this:

**Point of definition** vs **Point of instantiation**

> The **point of definition** of a template
>   is located immediately before its
>   definition. In this example, the point
>   of definition of the function template
>   g(T) is located **immediately before the
>   keyword template**. Because the function
>   call f(123) does not depend on a
>   template argument, the compiler will
>   consider names declared before the
>   definition of function template g(T).
>   Therefore, the call f(123) will call
>   f(double). Although f(int) is a better
>   match, it is not in scope at the point
>   of definition of g(T).
>
> The **point of instantiation** of a
>   template is located immediately before
>   the declaration that encloses its use.
>   In this example, the point of
>   instantiation of the call to
>   g(234) is located immediately
>   before i(). Because the function call
>   h(a) depends on a template argument,
>   the compiler will consider names
>   declared before the instantiation of
>   function template g(T). Therefore, the
>   call h(a) will call h(double). It will
>   not consider h(int), because this
>   function was not in scope at the point
>   of instantiation of g(234).

Quoted from [Name binding and dependent names (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/compbgpl/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.bg.doc/language_ref/name_binding.htm)

Although, it talks about function template, the same is true of class template as well.

Comment: @David Rodríguez: Edited my post :D

Comment: that what I was thinking, just wanted to get second opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It is a class template and it's definition starts from the word `template`.

From Standard docs., *14.1*,

> A template defines a family of classes or functions, or an alias for a family of types.
>   `template-declaration:
>   exportopt template < template-parameter-list > declaration`

And,

> A template-declaration is a declaration. **A template-declaration is also a definition if its declaration defines a function,
>   a class, or a static data member.**

So, formally the template declaration is the definition for the templated class which starts with the word `template` in your example.

Comment: according to Bjarne (The Design and Evolution of C++ amongst others of his works) it is class template NOT template class.

Comment: if you editing do it correctly. Alex Farber said something what was wrong and now reading your answer it looks like he said something different to what he really said.